# How to reset animation curves in graph editor

Tags: animation, graph-editor, fcurves

I changed up the curves in the graph editor however i would like to reset them back to automatic interpolation. I dont know how to do this and I cant seem to find a solid answer

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a direct way to do it but starting from that:

[image]

you could press <kbd>V</kbd> to change the interpolation mode to *Vector*:

[image]

then press <kbd>V</kbd> again to choose *Automatic*:

[image]

and you'll be back to the default interpolation:

[image]